# ChkTeX Regex WARNING "Compilation regular expression" on macOS

Tags: chktex

I'm experiencing a consistent problem with ChkTeX on my macOS system and am looking for solutions. The issue occurs every time I run ChkTeX. I get the following warning:

```
> chktex main.tex                                                                                                                    
ChkTeX v1.7.8 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
chktex: WARNING -- Compilation of regular expression \[(?![^\]\[{}]*{(?![^\]\[{}]*}))[^\]]*\[ failed with error repetition-operator operand invalid.

No errors printed; No warnings printed; No user suppressed warnings; No line suppressed warnings.
```

This problem arises regardless of the LaTeX document, even with simpler ones. Strangely, this issue prevents Visual Studio Code from parsing the ChkTeX output correctly. Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for catching that, especially for going through the trouble to report a bug.  I have pushed a fix, but until then you can just delete that line from the chktexrc file.  You can find which file it is using by running `chktex -d 4`.

Comment: Do you know what happened to the fix? TeX Live 2024 still generates this error.

Comment: Is it line 247 which needs deleting? The expression isn't a perfect match, but I'm not certain what's escaped in the warning message. It also appears `chktex` isn't compiled with the `-d` option on Windows ....