# Chktex regex warning on Arch Linux

Tags: chktex

This issue is related to this one:
[ChkTeX Regex WARNING "Compilation regular expression" on macOS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703710/chktex-regex-warning-compilation-regular-expression-on-macos)
Parsing a simple latex file gives me a warning.
I am using the latest release of chktex.
Can this be fixed by releasing a new version of chktex?

Comment: Welcome! This is probably not the place to ask this question. How do the docs tell you to report bugs? In any case, nobody is likely to be able to find a fix for an unspecified warning generated when parsing unknown input. What warning do you get? With which input?

Comment: This should really be a comment on the answer there or raised elsewhere. Here, it's essentially a duplicate. There's an email address in the manual page you could try. Wherever the fix was pushed to, it doesn't appear to have been CTAN. See https://www.nongnu.org/chktex/ for contact details.